# inequality with one number and a sum of numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, numerical-methods

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n $ be non-zero real number,  such that $\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}=1$. Show that for any $i = 1, \ldots, n$, 
$$|x_i| \leq \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}{n}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt n}.$$

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when $x_i=x_j$ for all $i\neq j$? Or see @RossMillikan's example. Your inequality is false.

Comment: The right inequality can be replaced by an equal sign, as the numerator in the middle is $1$.  But the left one is still incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality is false. It says that every $x_i^2$ is at most the average of the $x_i^2$’s, which is true if and only if $|x_1|=\ldots=|x_n|$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The second inequality follows immediately since $$\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: The second inequality I know :-) But how about the first one?

Answer (score 1):

What about $n=2, x_1=0, x_2=1, i=2?$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $x_i$ are non-zero numbers.

Comment: Alex, take $i=4$, and $x_i=1/2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. You get equality, not an inequality.

Comment: @Alex:  it still fails if $n=2, x_1=0.1, x_2=\sqrt{0.99}, i=2$